# Pretty equations in HoldForm[]

Tags: replacement, hold, traditional-form

I have been generating equations programmatically, resulting in lists that look like this:

```
{Log[2,(4^4)^3, 3 (Mod[2,4] 4), Log[root[2, 3], 4^4]}
```

where 'root[x,y]' represents x^(1/y).

These are all equations in `HoldForm[]`; If I were to `ReleaseForm[]`, each one would immediate collapse to 24 (in this example).

For the purpose of display, I would like these to appear in more traditional form, such that people not accustomed to Mathematica can more readily understand them. This means some combination of superscripting powers, subscripting Logarithmic bases, and *most importantly*, converting the root command to be shown with a root symbol. I recognize there are several ways this could be done. Here is one:

[image: readable equations]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using `Defer[]` + `TraditionalForm[]`?

Comment: For the root, you can use `Surd`